# compare new CGPoint value to a CGPoint value in Array

Tags: ios, ipad, nsarray, cgpoint, fast-enumeration

I'm generating a number of circles with random positions. what I want to prevent is the circles from overlapping each other. so I want to compare the newly generated CGPoint value to the ones that are in the array and have it generate a new value if the value finds itself in the radius area of one of the CGPoints.

I got most of it except for the overlapping thing.
I've commented the part out of something I tried, but that doesn't really work(flawed logic).
I'm not sure how to iterate through the individual values of the CGPoint and comparing them.

**UPDATE:**
I've change the code a bit more and added a check to see whether the CGPoint will overlap or not. Problem is whenever I want to try something like

```
while (!xPointOk || !yPointOk) {

// generate new values

}
```

I keep falling in an infinite loop.

```
- (void) positionCircles 
{

    //generate random Y value within a range
    int fromNumberY = 500;
    int toNumberY = 950;
    int randomNumberY =(arc4random()%(toNumberY-fromNumberY+1))+fromNumberY;

    //generate random Y value within a range
    int fromNumberX = 0;
    int toNumberX = 700;
    int randomNumberX = (arc4random()%(toNumberX-fromNumberX+1))+fromNumberX;

    //array to hold all the the CGPoints
    positionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    CGPoint circlePositionValue;

    CGFloat radius = 70;

    CGRect position = CGRectMake(randomNumberX,randomNumberY, radius, radius);

    [self makeColors];



    // create a circle for each color in color array
    for (int i = 0; i < [colors count];i++)
    {
        // generate new position before placing new cirlce
        randomNumberX = (arc4random()%(toNumberX-fromNumberX+1))+fromNumberX;
        randomNumberY = (arc4random()%(toNumberY-fromNumberY+1))+fromNumberY;

        circlePositionValue = CGPointMake(position.origin.x, position.origin.y);

        for (NSValue *value in positionsArray) {


            BOOL xPointOk = (randomNumberX < value.CGPointValue.x - radius) || 
                             (randomNumberX > value.CGPointValue.x + radius);

            BOOL yPointOk = (randomNumberY < value.CGPointValue.y - radius) || 
                             (randomNumberY > value.CGPointValue.y + radius);


            NSLog(@"xPoint: %i - %f", randomNumberX , value.CGPointValue.x);
            NSLog(@"xPoint ok? %@", xPointOk?@"yes":@"no");

            NSLog(@"yPoint: %i - %f", randomNumberY , value.CGPointValue.y);
            NSLog(@"yPoint ok? %@", yPointOk?@"yes":@"no");
            NSLog(@"___");

        }

        position.origin.x = randomNumberX;
        position.origin.y = randomNumberY;
        [positionsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:circlePositionValue]];

        Circle *myCircle = [[Circle alloc] initWithFrame:position radius:radius color:[colors objectAtIndex:i]];
        myCircle.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];
        [self.view addSubview:myCircle];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test should fail when the new point is less than the circumference away from any of the existing  points so you can use basic trig to work it out.

```
BOOL far_enough_away = NO;
CGPoint newpoint = CGZeroPoint;
while(!far_enough_away)
{
    newpoint = randomisation_thingy();
    far_enough_away = YES;
    for(NSValue *existing in positionsArray)
    {
        CGPoint pointb = [existing pointValue];
        CGFloat deltay = pointb.y-newpoint.y;
        CGFloat deltax = pointb.x-newpoint.x;
        CGFloat distance = sqrt(pow(deltax,2) + pow(deltay,2));
        //fail if closer than desired radius
        if(distance < circumference )
        {
           //sadness - try again
           far_enough_away = NO;
           break;
        }
    }
}
create_a_new_circle_at_point(newpoint);
```

Other things you need to consider are how many times to retry to stop an infinite number of retries.

Comment: hello, I tried incorporating your code into mine. but I didn't seem to get it working. While I understand that your way is definitely allot more efficient. would I be able to get it working without using trig?

Comment: It's pseudo code. Dont just copy/paste. Adapt what you see there to your program. And no, you'll need to use basic trigonometry to solve this problem.

Comment: yeah I got it working now. thanks! though I need to learn some basic trig :)